# Переустановка или откат Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ос, откат

Доброй ночи.
Имеется установленная с завода (или магазина) Windows 8.1.
Я так понимаю она лицензионная и ключ вшит в BIOS или куда его там вшивают с недавних пор. 
Как переустановить в данном случаи Windows? Диска у меня нету. Ключа нету (не факт что тот ключ который я вытянул с помощью Everest подойдет).

Или можно же просто как-то откатить систему до заводских настроек? При этом откат будет по эффективности такой же самый как переустановка?
Нужно "начать с чистого листа".

Comment: не могу ответить точно на ваш вопрос, но десятую винду обещают раздавать бесплатно даже тем, у кого стоит паленая восьмерка, поэтому если в ближайшее время не удастся найти "легальный" метод, то я бы попробовал вообще любым способом. На самом деле сам сейчас в аналогичной ситуации нахожусь, потому что ключ от десктопной версии утерян, и она легальная, пока просто стоит.

Comment: 1. По идее во всех Windows (начиная с XP) есть такая штука, как восстановление системы. Если Вы ее не выключали, то можно откатиться до какого-то момента в прошлом. 2. Если не боитесь вирусов и троянов всегда есть торренты. 3. Если не используете какого-то особого only-Windows софта, можно поставить Ubuntu\Mint и не переживать.

Answer (score 1):

Открываете выплывающую панель, там будет пункт Параметры. Далее Изменение параметров системы. И далее Обновление или восстановление.
При восстановлении предстоит выбрать кучу опций, в частности, вы можете сохранить данные при переустановке системы, а можете все под чистую отформатировать и так далее. Процедура несложная, занимаете не более 40 минут.
Ключ, насколько я помню не нужен, так как у меня его не было, но я переустанавливал, но вроде потребуется при установке учетная запись майкрософт. Там на одном из экранов вводите эмейл, на который отправляется ключ, и тут желательно, чтобы был доступ к электронной почте, чтобы можно было сразу этот ключ прочитать и ввести при установке.